# Por que números(long, int) iniciados com 0, acabam tendo outros valores?

Tags: java

Estava fazendo alguns testes em um formatador de números telefônicos, quando tentei essa entrada para um `long`: `033222221111L`, compilou normalmente (Sim, no mundo real não faria sentido uma entrada como essa, se tratando de um valor numérico). Mas o que me deixou intrigado foi pelo fato da saída, ser `(036)6222-5993` onde o esperado era `(033)22222-1111`, então debugando vi que não havia nada de errado com meu formatador telefônico, e sim com numero passado, pois o valor que estava vindo para o método era `3662225993` ao invés de `33222221111`, que seria a natural no mundo real.

Assim sendo, gostaria de conhecer o motivo pelo qual isso acontece? E qual a lógica para que `033222221111L` se torne `3662225993`?

Simplicando o exemplo:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(033222221111L)); 
// output = 3662225993 ?????
```

**Edit 1**

Sendo que o `0` é para representar que o valor é `octal`, o por que dessa escolha pelo 0(zero), já que pode causar facilmente confusão, como em meu caso, é herança do **C**?

Comment: se trata de uma entrada em formato "Octal" (diferente do sistema decimal que utilizamos) devido o prefixo "0" na frente, é como o "0x" para hexadecimais

Comment: @LeonardoBosquett, achei que seria algum código de formatação de entrada mesmo. Só não entendo por que utilizar o 0, já que pode ser facilmente confundido. Para hexadecimais é `0x`, que faz mas sentido.

Comment: Sobre o prefixo "0", parece ser histórico: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835465/where-did-the-octal-hex-notations-come-from

Comment: @Math, procurei aqui, para ver se achava algo e nada, até já sabia a [resposta para a pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970039/09-is-not-recognized-where-as-9-is-recognized), do SOen, mais gostaria de uma versão em Português, mas agora não sei se removo a pergunta? Ou deixo fecha-la como duplicada, para facilitar futuras buscas pelos mesmos termos? O que acha?

Comment: @Fernando duplicadas quando criadas organicamente costumam ser benéficas ao site, eu acho que não há a necessidade de deletar, até mesmo por que você pode perceber que a pergunta lá foi feita de uma maneira completamente diferente da sua. Além disso é importante vermos se elas realmente são duplicadas, pelo que eu entendi são sim, mas veja se lhe resta alguma dúvida que pode fazer com que a sua permaneça aberta em busca de algo que a resposta de lá não lhe atende.

Comment: @Math, a unica duvida que resta em relação a sua resposta a pergunta "possivelmente duplicada", é "por que cargas d'agua" foi utilizada o valor 0 (zero) para isso? Já que o link do LeonardoBosquett, não é muito convincente, por a resposta aceita lá começar com "I dunno ..." (Eu acho ... ou Eu não sei ...), apesar de fazer até algum sentido. =D

Comment: @Math, analisando melhor as duas perguntas, o que eu me parece que é perguntas distintas com respostas iguais, pois a pergunta lá nem trata de iniciar com 0, e sim de inteiro em geral. Mesmo que aqui seja fechado sem resposta, talvez seja interessante manter para levar até a resposta. Vou ver se tem algo no Meta a respeito.